# Fast synch mode slowed down after 200Gb

Tags: synchronization

It took 2 days to get to 200gb on geth fast synch mode. But now im moving with approx 5gb a day with a decent internet speed around 100mb/s in Lan.

I disconnected and now running on 25mb/s with wifi. But again the intial 200gb that was synched was with the 25mbs wifi

I should also mention I have a 11Gb msi geo force and 64 gb rams.

Altough, the system is sdd, i also have hdd to keep things neat. 
I created a mklink from sdd C: to hdd E: where the node is being stored. 
Since the intial 200gb was very fast I do not believe this slow pace is being caused by the mklink to hdd (read-write) folder. 
But I need to be sure that is not the case. And this is where my question is? Did the synch slow down after 200gb download due to hdd??

Cuz with this rate it ll probably take me 170 days to fully synch. I am also new at the community. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is your question ? Please format your text block. It is very hard to get things clear with so much stuff said in one paragraph.

Comment: Formatted with a question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's basically impossible to get synchronized with a HDD.

Initially everything works just fine as you are simply downloading the existing blockchain and going through it with no time pressure on your HDD so it works quite well. But when you start to reach the present state of the blockchain your HDD will basically run out of I/O - it can't process the data fast enough to get synchronized.

According to https://etherscan.io/chartsync/chaindefault Geth full node takes about 350GB. As far as I know fast node should be the same size (even if it synchronizes faster) so I'm not sure why you're hitting your limit at 200GB.

Anyway, the bottom line is that you will not be able to get synchronized on a HDD due to its poor I/O performance.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. So I changed the folder to my C drive which is a sdd. And my download speed is 100mb/s .But its still slow imo. Im downloading 10gb per day. Is that normal?

Comment: It's not only downloading, it's doing a lot of other work as well. It's probably quite normal that won't reach your "regular" downloading speeds, probably the bottle neck is not your bandwidth anyway but something else - but you should get synchronized eventually as it's an SSD.

Comment: I thought it was because I stopped the fast synch mode once. Then started again. So I read somewhere that once your stop the fast synch mode, it always start with full mode till fully synched. Then i deleted the all chain folder and restarted with fast synch on sdd drive and same thing. Once I hit around 200GB ,the synching slows down. I mean I have pretty fast GPU too with 14gb and 64 gm rams running. What do you think the bottleneck is at 200gb threshold?

Comment: Sorry, I'm really not an expert in synchronization issues, I've only ever used light sync myself so no idea